# "Run gradlew error" in react native while building apk

Tags: android, react-native, eas

Running 'gradlew :app:assembleRelease' in /home/expo/workingdir/build/android
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0.1-all.zip
10%
20%.
30%
40%.
50%
60
%.
70%.
80
%.
90%.
100%
Welcome to Gradle 8.0.1!
Here are the highlights of this release:

- Improvements to the Kotlin DSL
- Fine-grained parallelism from the first build with configuration cache
- Configurable Gradle user home cache cleanup
  For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/release-notes.html
  To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon.
  Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build

> Task :expo-updates-gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors
> Task :expo-updates-gradle-plugin:processResources
> Task :gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors
> Task :gradle-plugin:processResources
> Task :gradle-plugin:compileKotlin
> Task :gradle-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :gradle-plugin:classes
> Task :gradle-plugin:jar
> Task :gradle-plugin:inspectClassesForKotlinIC
> Task :expo-updates-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin
> Task :expo-updates-gradle-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :expo-updates-gradle-plugin:classes
> Task :expo-updates-gradle-plugin:jar
> Task :expo-updates-gradle-plugin:inspectClassesForKotlinIC
> Configure project :app
> ℹ️  Applying gradle plugin 'expo-updates-gradle-plugin' (expo-updates@0.18.18)
> Configure project :expo-modules-core
> Checking the license for package NDK (Side by side) 23.1.7779620 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/licenses
> License for package NDK (Side by side) 23.1.7779620 accepted.
> Preparing "Install NDK (Side by side) 23.1.7779620 (revision: 23.1.7779620)".
> "Install NDK (Side by side) 23.1.7779620 (revision: 23.1.7779620)" ready.
> Installing NDK (Side by side) 23.1.7779620 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620
> "Install NDK (Side by side) 23.1.7779620 (revision: 23.1.7779620)" complete.
> "Install NDK (Side by side) 23.1.7779620 (revision: 23.1.7779620)" finished.
> Checking the license for package CMake 3.22.1 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/licenses
> License for package CMake 3.22.1 accepted.
> Preparing "Install CMake 3.22.1 (revision: 3.22.1)".
> "Install CMake 3.22.1 (revision: 3.22.1)" ready.
> Installing CMake 3.22.1 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.22.1
> "Install CMake 3.22.1 (revision: 3.22.1)" complete.
> "Install CMake 3.22.1 (revision: 3.22.1)" finished.
> FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
> 1: Task failed with an exception.

---

- Where:
  Build file '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-sample-pedometer/android/build.gradle' line: 40
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo-sample-pedometer'.

> Could not set unknown property 'classifier' for task ':expo-sample-pedometer:androidSourcesJar' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================
> 2: Task failed with an exception.

---

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':expo'.

> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  BUILD FAILED in 2m 33s
  10 actionable tasks: 10 executed
  Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.

So I was about to deploy my thesis into google play store and somehow and when I tried: eas build -p android --profile preview it stops here

Comment: You have a line stating that: "compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle". Look inside your project and find the build.gradle file. See if the compileSdkVersion is defined there.